# How to delete output attributes of the group output geometry node

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

While trying arround I created some output attributes in the group output node of my geometry nodes:

[image]

How can I remove them again?

I could not find a way to do it. Even if I delete the group output node and add it again, it keeps the output attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Geometry Node editor, open the side panel (Shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>) and select the *Group* tab.  In the *Output* panel, select the name of the attribute you want to delete.  Click the minus sign.

[image: Geometry Node editor side panel with Group and delete highlighted]

In my example, I've just selected *Vector*. When I click the highlighted minus sign, it will be removed.